# how to create a candle chart in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, candlestick-chart, technical-indicator

Is there anyway to draw a candle chart in flutter?

I want some thing like this :
[image]

important: the left side toolbar is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package for candlestick and other charts : [syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^19.3.53](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts)

See example here:
https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-charts/chart-types/candle-chart